# How do I change the alignment of an image by a fixed dp amount in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have a requirement for users to upload images that can be resized and manually aligned inside a frame, like for a profile image. My problem is displaying the image after the information has been captured.

When trying to apply an alignment offset, the offset always seems to get applied after the image is cropped, so it looks like the cropped image gets shifted instead of the image simply being realigned.

Say I start with a basic [image of a cat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmurv.jpg) that I want to crop and shift down slightly on a card. I have tried multiple variations of this code with offsets and graphic layer translations with similar results.

```
Card(
    colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(
        containerColor = Color.Cyan
    ),
    shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp),
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(vertical = 16.dp, horizontal = 16.dp)
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .aspectRatio(1.2f)
) {
    Image(
        painterResource(id = R.drawable.test_image),
        contentDescription = null,
        modifier = Modifier
            .offset(x = 0.dp, y = 40.dp)
            .fillMaxSize(),
        contentScale = ContentScale.FillWidth
    )
}
```

I get a [cat with it's ears clipped off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5XmZ.png). All the while, there is plenty of space on the card for more of the image.

Aligning the image to the top or bottom does part of what I would expect. It moves the image within the frame. However, I don't want to top align the image, but somewhere between center and top by a predefined number of DPs.

How do I shift the image down slightly so the ears aren't clipped, yet the image remains scaled to the defined frame?

Thanks!

Comment: If you are aligning after cropping, there is no data about the image before cropping. Only the cropped image can be re aligned

Comment: @Abhimanyu I'm not intentionally cropping the image. In my mind, the contentScale should be resizing the image to the parent, not cropping it to the parent. As mentioned, aligning the image works, but it's to an extreme (ie: Center or Top). I just want to shift/align the image a little before the parent clips and renders it. Kind of like focusing a portrait picture on the face so the face is in the center. Thanks!

Comment: @Raghunandan thanks! I'm not really looking for a cropping library. Just trying to realign an image within the bounds of its parent.

Comment: no worries glad the answer below worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is a (custom) alignment. You can try [`BiasAlignment`](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/9290fdcf12ac5cfddbd208ee0fd4e9ffd5afb06f:compose/ui/ui/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/Alignment.kt;l=153). `BiasAlignment(0F, 0F)` aligns to the center, `BiasAlignment(0F, -1F)` aligns to the top center. Since you want something in between, you can try something like `BiasAlignment(0F, -0.2F)`.

If you rather want a specific number of dps (pixels), you will have to implement custom `Alignment`. It can look like this:

```kotlin
class MySpecialAlignment(
  val verticalShift: Float,
) : Alignment {
  override fun align(size: IntSize, space: IntSize, layoutDirection: LayoutDirection): IntOffset {
    val centerX = (space.width - size.width).toFloat() / 2f
    val centerY = (space.height - size.height).toFloat() / 2f
    val shiftedY = centerY + verticalShift
    return IntOffset(centerX.roundToInt(), shiftedY.roundToInt())
  }
}
```

You will then use it like this:

```kotlin
val verticalShift = LocalDensity.current.run { (-10).dp.toPx() }
Image(
    alignment = MySpecialAlignment(verticalShift)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Jan Bína's answer, I created a new data class called PixelAlignment.

```
@Immutable
data class PixelAlignment (
    val offsetX: Float,
    val offsetY: Float
) : Alignment {

    override fun align(size: IntSize, space: IntSize, layoutDirection: LayoutDirection): IntOffset {
        val centerX = (space.width - size.width).toFloat() / 2f
        val centerY = (space.height - size.height).toFloat() / 2f

        val x = centerX + offsetX
        val y = centerY + offsetY

        return IntOffset(x.roundToInt(), y.roundToInt())
    }
}
```

This data class gets applied similar to the original code.

```
Image(
    painterResource(id = R.drawable.test_image),
    contentDescription = null,
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize(),
    alignment = PixelAlignment(0f, 100f),
    contentScale = ContentScale.FillWidth
)
```

The result of the original cat now [looks as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Pg0o.png).